# ¿Qué palabra puede usarse para referirse a dos "cosas" que tienen algo en común?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Varias veces me pasa que tengo que referirme a dos "cosas" distintas pero que tienen algo en común, y no sé como referirme a estas. No quiero usar la palabra "cosas", justamente.

Supongamos que estoy hablando de la electrónica y la carpintería. Una es una ciencia y la otra es una artesanía. ¿Qué palabra podría usar para referirme a las dos juntas?

¿Podría decir que son dos "actividades" tal vez y decir "estas actividades... bla bla"? En este caso puede funcionar, ¿pero qué tal si tuviera que hablar de dos "cosas" mucho más diferentes? Por ejemplo, por la razón que fuera, tendría que hablar a la vez de un caramelo y de una doctrina (es un caso sin sentido pero no se me ocurre un caso más concreto para ilustrar el ejemplo ahora). ¿Qué tienen en común? ¿Qué palabra podría usar para referirme a estas dos "cosas" a la vez?

Una palabra que se me ocurre, pero que no estoy seguro, es "entidad" o "ente", que se describe como "cosa o ser que tiene existencia real o imaginaria". Entonces en mi ejemplo tanto un caramelo como una doctrina serian "cosas que tienen una existencia real o imaginaria". ¿Podría ser? ¿Qué palabra puede usarse para referirse a dos "cosas" diferentes pero que necesitas referirte a ellas con una sola palabra por algo que tienen en común?

Comment: Buena pregunta, pero no puedo darte el +1 hasta mañana porque he usado todos los votos permitidos por día. Cuando pase un día te dejo el voto.

Comment: Conceptos, materias, ideas. // Quisiera ver una frase con ______ donde debe ir la palabra que buscas, por favor.

Comment: @aparente001 es que varias veces se me dio en situaciones distintas, pero tienen algo en común. Un ejemplo podría ser el de artesanías y electrónica. "Artesanía y electrónica. Aquellos que trabajan en estas ____ ". Pero lo que busco es algo mucho más genérico. Por ejemplo. "Un caramelo y una doctrina. Ambas _____ son representadas en la mente a través de redes neuronales bla bla".

Comment: Me parece que la palabra que busco es ente o entidad, pero no estoy seguro. Todo aquello, material o inmaterial, que existe. Son oraciones que siempre terminas rellenando con la palabra "cosa" antes de decirla, porque escribir una oración con la palabra cosa es impresentable

Comment: Sospecho que la palabra apta va a variar según el contexto.  He visto "entidad" en un curso de diseño de bases de datos, pero aparte de eso, no le veo mucho uso.  Ejemplos: 1. Artesanía y electrónica. Aquellos que trabajan en estos *campos* etc. 2. Un caramelo y una doctrina. Ambos *conceptos* son representados en la mente a través de redes neuronales bla bla.  Es decir, escojo la *clase* or *conjunto* que incluye las dos palabras (o cosas) según lo que voy a hacer con las dos palabras en el resto de la frase o párrafo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No vas a poder usar un término para "cosas" que pueden tener algo en común si admites que "pueden no tener tanto (o nada) en común". Si tienen algo en común podrás usar esa "raíz" y si no lo tienen tendrás que usar un término más genérico.

"[Cosa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B3yTydM)" es desde luego el término más genérico para designar un concepto, por el amplio rango de elementos que puede abarcar.

Una "cosa" tiene "tiene entidad, ya sea corporal o espiritual, natural o artificial, concreta, abstracta o virtual", pero "concepto", "entidad", "elemento" u "objeto" suenan menos coloquiales, aunque el rango de entes que pueden representar cada uno es más restringido ("objeto" desde luego se refiere a un ente físico).

Otras formas más coloquiales incluso que "cosa" serían "movida" o "historia".

El problema es que puede ser que quieras usar el término para agrupar *cosas* que pueden no tener tanto en común. Si fuesen *entes* de la misma naturaleza, ya sera física o abstracta, puedes referirte a ellos por lo que son o lo que quieres recalcar de ellos. En tu ejemplo de electrónica y carpintería podrías incluso decir que son *hobbies* o *aficiones*, dependiendo de tu contexto.

Si son *cosas* que no tienen ninguna relación ("un caramelo y [...] una doctrina") evidentemente al no tener nada en común necesitas buscar un término más genérico que los agrupe a los dos, pero entonces (oh, paradoja) no tienen **algo** en común.

Resumiendo, si tienen algo en común, ya sea una cualidad intrínseca o percibida puedes usar eso.

Si no tienen nada en común tendrás que usar términos genéricos que puedan abarcar lo máximo posible y aun así dependerás del contexto (cómo y por qué los estás comparando): Cosa, entidad, ente, concepto, ...

Comment: En realidad las "cosas" siempre tienen como mínimo algo en común, existen, tienen una representación en la mente, etc. Si estás hablando en un contexto de por ejemplo, cómo se representan o se almacenan las "cosas" en la mente, te puede venir la necesidad de referirte a un caramelo y una doctrina como "cosas" (la palabra que quiero evitar!) que se representan en la mente. Concepto podría ser otra, creo que en algun momento se me cruzó por la cabeza también, aunque no estoy seguro si concepto se refiere solo a ideas o también a objetos materiales, ahi doctrina si seria concepto y caramelo no

Answer (score 2):

No estoy muy seguro de que sea esto lo que buscas, pero tal vez podrías usar el adjetivo "análogo":

> **[análogo, ga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2VyUum7)**
>
> 1. adj. Que tiene analogía con algo.

Y a su vez:

> **[analogía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2Vt6TRt)**
>
> 1. f. Relación de semejanza entre cosas distintas.

Luego dos (objetos/temas/asuntos/cosas) análogos lo son porque tienen una relación de semejanza, algo en común. La verdad es que suena raro pero si nos ceñimos a esta definición, podríamos decir:

> ...como lo son la electrónica y la carpintería. Estos dos análogos basan su semejanza en el hecho de...

También podemos orientar el asunto de otra manera: si has conseguido establecer una semejanza (sea cual fuere) entre dos objetos cualesquiera, formarán parte de una enumeración de objetos que comparten algo. Cada uno de los componentes de dicha enumeración será un "elemento":

> **[elemento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EWqThMH)**
>
> 8. m. *Mat.* Cada uno de los componentes de un conjunto.

Así pues, y repasando el ejemplo más extremo, podríamos decir:

> Ejemplos que comparten esta característica son los caramelos y las doctrinas. Cada uno de estos elementos tiene la peculiaridad de que...

Answer (score 0):

Podria ser "ejemplos en cuestion" para no aludir sobre que hablamos, si es alguna disciplina, objeto, idea, personas, conceptos, formas, etc.,   la palabra cosa hasta en derecho se utiliza como "cosa juzgada"